# How to make a Qt dialog read-only?

Tags: qt, dialog

How to make a QT dialog read-only? Any general way to implement it easily? For example

(1) set all its containing widgets disable. (how to implement it?)

(2) Intercept edit events like key pressed, mouse pressed but how not to intercept the one to close the dialog?

I think this feature should be very helpful.

Comment: This is pretty vague, could you add a piece of code what you have - and what you'd like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the widgets can be done similar to the following:

```
void myDialog::disableWidgets()
{
  QList<QWidget *> widgets = this->findChildren<QWidget *>();

  foreach(QWidget* widget, widgets)
  {
    widget->setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To intercept events, QDialog includes the function installEventFilter(QObject*).

This allows you to use a separate object to receive all events passed to the dialog. You can then choose to handle the event in the object, or pass it on to the dialog itself by calling the base class QObject::eventFilter

```
class MyEventHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:

    bool MyEventHandler::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        // handle key press events
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            // Do something
            // ...
            return true; // event handled by the class
        }
        else
        {   // ignore this event and pass it to the dialog as usual
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
    }

    return false;
};


QDialog* dlg = new QDialog;
MyEventHandler evtHandler = new MyEventHandler;

dlg->installEventFilter(evtHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read-only is a strange term to apply to a dialog.  Disabling all widgets as above does the trick.  If you only wanted to make the input part of a QInputDialog read-only (while leaving scrollbars, buttons, etc. enabled), you could adapt that code as below:

```
  QInputDialog dialog(this);
  dialog.setOptions(QInputDialog::UsePlainTextEditForTextInput);
  dialog.setWindowTitle("Title");
  dialog.setLabelText("Label");
  dialog.setTextValue("1\n2\n3\n");

  QList<QWidget *> widgets = dialog.findChildren<QWidget *>();
  foreach(QWidget* widget, widgets) {
    if (strcmp(widget->metaObject()->className(),"QPlainTextEdit")==0) {
      QPlainTextEdit *t = static_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(widget);
      t->setReadOnly(true);
    }
  }

  dialog.exec();
```